# Variable height of view in different screens with iOS AutoLayout And SizeClass in Storyboard or xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, size-classes

Steps:

1.I use SizeClass "compact width, any height"

2.I set the view's height 40px to fit for the 3.5/4.0/4.5/4.7 inch screen

3.I change SizeClass to "compact width, regular height"

4.I want set the view's height 60px to fit for the 5.5 inch screen

5.When I run simulator with iphone6+ the view's height is 60px this is right

6.When I run simulator with iphone4/iphone5/iphone5s/iphone6 the view's height is 60px but i want 3.5/4.0/4.5/4.7 inch screen is 40px

How can I realize variable height of view in different screens with AutoLayout And SizeClass in storyboard or xib
I want view's height 60px in 5.5             inch screen
I want view's height 40px in 3.5/4.0/4.5/4.7 inch screen

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this via SizeClasses because in portrait, *iPhone 6, iPhone 5, and iPhone 4s* use the **compact horizontal** and **regular vertical** size classes. So it is the same as *iPhone 6 Plus* uses the **compact horizontal** and **regular vertical** size classes in portrait. Please, see the following source [Adaptivity and Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help, how can I realize this effect?

Comment: You cannot realize this via interface builder! Because in portrait mode 5.5 inch screen has the same size class as 3.5/4.0/4.5/4.7 inch screens. Therefore application cannot distinguish iPhone 6+ and other iPhones in Portrait! You can implement your feature only programmatically. The simplest way: to get screen size and determine if the height is longer then 735, for example:   
if ((UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) && (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height > 735)) {
 buttonHeightConstraint.constant = 60
}else{
 buttonHeightConstraint.constant = 40
}

Comment: if a view there are too many controls such as UILabel, I must rotation each  UILabel and set property of each UILabel, have another simplest way? @SoVa_